# Error "Generic Proxy does not exist" while selecting existing package in SE80

Tags: abap

I have an ABAP report, let's call it THE_REPORT_EXAMPLE_123 in a package THE_PACKAGE_EXAMPLE.

In SE38 I am able to find THE_REPORT_EXAMPLE_123, I see its source code and I can execute it.

But there's an issue while searching the package THE_PACKAGE_EXAMPLE:

1. Open se80 in SAP GUI
2. In the Repository Browser I am looking for "Package" and as the name of the package I am putting the real name of the existing package known to me
3. Then I am clicking on the eyeglass icon, but I get this message:

   > Generic Proxy THE_PACKAGE_EXAMPLE does not exist. Do you want to create the object?

[image: package not existing in se80]

What could be the reason?

Comment: Here, it's about Generic Proxy, not Package. How do you exactly try to find it in SE80, step by step?

Comment: Step by step:  1) open se80 in SAPlogon, 2) in the Repository Browser I am looking for "Package" and as the name of the package I am putting the real name of the exsiting package known to me, then I am clicking on the eyeglass icon.

Comment: We got the same bug in the SE80 in one of our systems.

Comment: I guess you need to contact the SAP support. I couldn't find an existing SAP note which describes that symptom. Note that you may also reach the packages through transaction codes SE21/SPACKAGE (and also via SE80 > Program > click button in the tree above the program name to display its parent object).

Comment: ...or finally switch to using Eclipse with the ADT packages.

Answer (score 0):

It happens. One probable cause is the inconsistency of TADIR entry for this package.

Several steps can be done:

1. SE80 -> Select package -> Utilities -> Rebuld object list

[image]

2. Select program `THE_REPORT_EXAMPLE_123` and run Utilities -> Update navigation index

[image]

If none of that helps, the last resort is the full consistency system check via STDR transaction. Check SAP note [1915580](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0001915580) for reference or use [this tutorial](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Basis/STDR+%3A+Is+this+safe+to+run+in+all+systems+for+SAP+and+customer+objects)

Use STDR only as a last resort (!!!) and if unsure, better delegate this to BASIS.